# Read a Special Character from bulleted List Item

Tags: google-apps-script, special-characters, google-docs, unicode-string, bulletedlist

I am writing a docs script to print something when certain characters appear in the document.
The problem is that I can't read bulleted-list special characters (check-marks for example)

I can read copied check-marks from a web page or a check mark that was added by script ( using append )  but it will not read a check mark added from the bulleted list.

Is there any way to read bulleted-list items?

```
function myFunction() {
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
var text = [] ;
text = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getParagraphs();
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) 
{
      if ( text[i].findText(String.fromCharCode(0x2713)) != null)
      {
             body.appendParagraph("Para");
       }
}}
```